# Replace text in xml loaded with simplexml_load_file()?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have this xml file:

```
<flats>
    <flat>

        <images1>http://www.example.com/image1.jpg</images1>
        <images2>http://www.example.com/image1.jpg</images2>

    </flat>
</flats>
```

Which I need to load using php and then replace some node names to get this (just change **image1** and **image2** to **images**:

```
<flats>
    <flat>

        <images>http://www.example.com/image1.jpg</images>
        <images>http://www.example.com/image1.jpg</images>

    </flat>
</flats>
```

I managed to load and save the file, but I don't know how to replace the node names.

```
$xml_external_path = 'http://external-site.com/original.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_external_path);

$xml->asXml('updated.xml');
```

**UPDATE:**
PHP

```
    $xml_external_path = 'http://external-site.com/original.xml';
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_external_path);
    print_r($xml);
    $newXml = str_replace( 'images1', 'image',$xml ) ;
    print_r($newXml);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to just rename the `<images1>` and `<images2>` tags I suggest you go with the simplest solution, i.e. text replace using `str_replace`.

```
$xml_external_path = 'http://external-site.com/original.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_external_path);

$searches = ['<images1>', '<images2>', '</images1>', '</images2>'];
$replacements = ['<images>', '<images>', '</images>', '</images>'];

$newXml = simplexml_load_string( str_replace( $searches, $replacements, $xml->asXml() ) );
$newXml->asXml('updated.xml');
```

If you however need a more sophisticated way to handle the task you may want to take a look at the [DOMDocument class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and build your own new XML

Comment: not working, $searches and $replacements are arrays? you do the saving before the str_replace function?¿

Comment: Yes, they're arrays. And can you be more specific how exactly is it not working? Btw if you're using PHP before 5.4 you can't use that short syntax and should use `$searches = array('<images1>', '<images2>', '</images1>', '</images2>');` and the same for $replacements.

Comment: I updated my answer. See at the bottom. No errors, the replacement doesn't work at all.

Comment: I think  a xml file is not a string where I can use str_replace.

Comment: I updated my answer to save the new XML into a file and btw from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php) `If the filename isn't specified, this function returns a string on success and FALSE on error.`

Answer (score 0):

Parse the original xml and create a new xml:

```
$oldxml = simplexml_load_file("/path/to/file.xml");

// create a new XML trunk
$newxml = simplexml_load_string("<flats><flat/></flats>");

// iterate over child-nodes of <flat>
// check their name 
// if name contains "images", add a new child in $newxml

foreach ($oldxml->flat->children() as $key => $value) 
    if (substr($key, 0, 6) == "images") 
        $newxml->flat->addChild("images", $value);

// display new XML:

echo $newxml->asXML();
```

see it working: https://eval.in/301221

**EDIT:** If all children of `<flat>` are `<imageX>`, no need for checking `$key`:

```
foreach ($oldxml->flat->children() as $value) 
    $newxml->flat->addChild("images", $value);
```

**EDIT:** Here's a short and sweet selection of nodes to be changed using `xpath`:

```
foreach ($oldxml->xpath("/flats/flat/*[starts-with(local-name(), 'images')]") as $value)
    $newxml->flat->addChild("images", $value);
```

The `xpath` statement above will select all children of `<flat>` starting with "images" and put them in an array.

see it working: https://eval.in/301233